# PHP returns SQL error when appending "AND" expression after "ORDER BY" expression in SQL query

Tags: php, sql

In documentation I can see ORDER BY expression is usually put at the end of the query, however, in my case, I want to order products by price first and then choose brands, as a result, I would add " AND product_brand IN" after ORDER BY product_price. Then PHP throw an error, i'm pretty sure it is because I put AND express after ORDER BY expression, how can I get over this?

```
if(isset($_POST['action'])) {
    $keyword =  $_POST['keyword'];
    $output = "";
    $query = "SELECT * FROM $keyword WHERE product_rating = '4.5'";
    if (isset($_POST['general'])) {
        $general_filter = implode("','", $_POST['general']);
        switch ($general_filter) {
            case 'all':
                $query .= "";
                break;
            case 'low_to_high':
                $query .= "ORDER BY product_new_price ASC";
                break;
            case 'high_to_low':
                $query .= "ORDER BY product_new_price DESC";
                break;
            case 'name_ascending':
                $query .= "ORDER BY product_title ASC";
                break;
            case 'name_descending':
                $query .= "ORDER BY product_title DESC";
                break;
            case 'newest':
                $query .= "ORDER BY product_date DESC";
                    break;
            case 'top_seller':
                $query .= "ORDER BY product_sold ASC";
                break;
            case 'available':
                $query .= "AND product_status = '1'";
                break;
        }
    }
    if (isset($_POST['brand'])) {
        $brand_filter = implode(",", $_POST['brand']);
        if ($brand_filter == 'all') {
            $query .= "";
        }
        else {
            $query .= " AND product_brand IN ('$brand_filter')";
        }
    }
```

I search for hours on internet and still stuck.

Comment: can you paste the error here?

Comment: You are open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized prepared statements instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even data from the database, [you are still at risk of corrupting your data](https://bobby-tables.com/). If this is a school project. Best time to learn. How to do things right.

Comment: Seems like you get a `case 'available':` after started with the ORDER BY. You have to take care of the complete WHERE before doing (one) ORDER BY.

Comment: Error here:
Fatal error
: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND product_brand IN ('Samsung')' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\tinhocngoisao\fetch_data.php:58 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\tinhocngoisao\fetch_data.php(58): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in
C:\xampp\htdocs\tinhocngoisao\fetch_data.php
on line
58

Comment: `I want to order products by price first and then choose brands, as a result, I would add " AND product_brand IN" after ORDER BY product_price`...that's just not how SQL works. The WHERE clause must always be before the ORDER BY clause. So re-arrange your code so that it builds the SQL query string in the correct order (regardless of what order your PHP code makes the decisions about what to put into the query, it must at least bring it all together in the right order. I'd save each SQL clause in a separate PHP variable (which can appended to separately) and then concatenate them at the end.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL has a specific order of commands. It is not allowed to have the orderBy before a WHERE clause.
You can solve this by moving the second if-statement up:

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM $keyword WHERE product_rating = '4.5'";
        if (isset($_POST['brand'])) {
                $brand_filter = implode(",", $_POST['brand']);
                if ($brand_filter == 'all') {
                    $query .= "";
                }
                else {
                    $query .= " AND product_brand IN ('$brand_filter')";
                }
        }
        if (isset($_POST['general'])) {
            $general_filter = implode("','", $_POST['general']);
            switch ($general_filter) {
                case 'all':
                    $query .= "";
                    break;
                case 'low_to_high':
                    $query .= "ORDER BY product_new_price ASC";
                    break;
                case 'high_to_low':
                    $query .= "ORDER BY product_new_price DESC";
                    break;
                case 'name_ascending':
                    $query .= "ORDER BY product_title ASC";
                    break;
                case 'name_descending':
                    $query .= "ORDER BY product_title DESC";
                    break;
                case 'newest':
                    $query .= "ORDER BY product_date DESC";
                        break;
                case 'top_seller':
                    $query .= "ORDER BY product_sold ASC";
                    break;
                case 'available':
                    $query .= "AND product_status = '1'";
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: well it really does the trick, the error gone but I can't understand why? As two if statements are the same level, if I select order by first, then the order by statement is still before "and expression", isn't it?

Comment: The resulting query will now be: SELECT * FROM $keyword WHERE product_rating = '4.5' AND product_brand IN ('$brand_filter') ORDER BY product_title ASC. SQL first wants to have all conditions, so the rows expected in the resultset are defined, and only then will it sort your resultset. It's just how SQL works, see https://www.universalclass.com/articles/computers/sql/using-the-where-and-order-by-clauses-in-sql.htm

Comment: Big thank to you, and other answerers too, my savers, have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

You can't add conditions after ORDER BY.
You should put those conditions in the WHERE clause.

Or if you want to ORDER BY more than one field just separate them with , .

Like: `ORDER BY product_title DESC, product_status = '1' ASC`  and so on.